# Regex for html string in Objective C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I am getting a `HTML` formatted string with tags. But there is an inconstancy with  "`<br>`" tag. I am getting"`<br>`" tag in random formats which causes some extra space in text. So is there any solution to trim these multiple "`<br>`" tags with single one?

Example of text :-

```
"some text..... <br>"
"some text..... <br> <br>"   // <-- this cause some extra space.
"some text..... <br>\n"    // <-- this cause some extra space.
"some text..... <br>\n<br>" // <-- this cause some extra space.
"some text..... <br><br>\n     <br>" // <-- this cause some extra space.
```

So in short, **there can be multiple "`<br>`" tags with white spaces and `\n` character in it.**

I need to replace that with single "`<br>`" tag. Can anyone help me with regex for the same?

**Note:-** I don't want to replace any other string in between two `"<br>"` tags except white space and "\n" .

**Code written till now -**

```
NSMutableString *temp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:html];

            [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<br><br>" withString:@"<br>" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
            [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>\n<br>" withString:@"<br>" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
            [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>\n" withString:@"<br>" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
```

It's a static string, needed `regex` for it.

Comment: one option can be obtaining the string between two `<br>` tags and trimming the string with `\n` and `space`. If the trimmed string is empty you can replace it altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[101 Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iU7dL6/1)

```
Find:    (<br>)(\s*\1)+
Replace: $1
```